# How to handle Timers correctly in Java?

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

I want my timer to execute the actionPerformed method only one time once it 5 seconds the time but it is writing in the console "Hello" lots of times:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class X{
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println( "Hello" );
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer( 5000, actionListener );
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

How can I make the effect I want? Thanks

Comment: What does `lots of times` mean? The code looks fine at first glance...

Comment: I meant it writes "Hello" forever.

Comment: To write "Hello" only one time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned, it's better to use `java.util.Timer`, but you can also use [setRepeats()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats%28boolean%29) before starting:

```
timer.setRepeats(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't neglect to use the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). There's nothing *wrong* with `java.util.Timer`, but [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) has several advantages with Swing.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class X {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                        System.out.println("Hello");
                    }
                };
                Timer timer = new Timer(5000, actionListener);
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If using `java.util.Timer`, update the GUI using a [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style#Continuations_as_objects).

Comment: Good question, but I think the down-vote is unwarranted. Absent posting a `Runnable` to the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), the initial thread may exit before the `javax.swing.Timer` fires, as it does on my platform.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a `java.util.Timer` rather than a `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: When I import javax.util.Timer Java doesn't let me call:  java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer( 5000, actionListener ); It says "he constructor Timer(int, ActionListener) is undefined". How can I make the same effect with Java.util?

Comment: @Rama not, never, don't use java.util.Timer for Swing GUI related Event, since javax.swing.Timer isn't accurate (in compare with java.util.Timer), but is best way for Java GUI based on Swing

Comment: If using `javax.util.Timer`, update the GUI using a [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style#Continuations_as_objects).

Comment: Yes, as @trashgod says, if you need to update the GUI, make sure the code that does it is running on the Event dispatcher thread. However, in your example you are not running any code that interacts with the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("Hello");

    }
  }
```

and then

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new MyTask(), 5000);
```

Comment: I like this solution but my class X needs to be Runnable so I implemented run to do other tasks...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
new JFrame().setVisible(true);
```